# Fill empty space

Tags: html, css, css-float, fill, autofill

Hi guys this is my problem (please visit the image link): http://dominioestudio.com/example.png

Im making a website and i cant figure it out how to fill the red space with the element below (the one into the cian rectangle).

This is the code from those elements (the gray contents)

```
.post {
  background: #CCC;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  float: left;
}
```

I can't use absolute position because the information of this website will change every day (so i need every element to be able to adapt / fill the space regardless the height of the others).

ideas?

Edit: some fo you ask me to make a jsfiddle. here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/sirmarcio/bLo5v79v/

Comment: Please show more code, or preferably create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Hi @IlpoOksanen already post the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sirmarcio/bLo5v79v/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `columns: auto 2;` in your `.grid-wrap` and `display:inline-block;` on your `.post` elements: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/bLo5v79v/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use css property:

```
.item {
  flex-grow: <number>; /* default 0 */
}
```

This defines the ability for a flex item to grow if necessary. It accepts a unitless value that serves as a proportion. It dictates what amount of the available space inside the flex container the item should take up.

If all items have flex-grow set to 1, every child will set to an equal size inside the container. If you were to give one of the children a value of 2, that child would take up twice as much space as the others.

Negative numbers are invalid.

This link will help you you learn more about flex property:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: this is really interesting, i didnt knew this property exist. anyways i cant make it work with any of his options. im editing my post to put a jsfiddle.